# Run PHP Script as a background process in AWS Beanstalk Post Install Hook

Tags: amazon-web-services, bash, elastic-beanstalk, bitbucket, bcbsn

## UDPATE

It turns out that this is the **wrong way to use elastic beanstalk**. The app would be running, however it would be a hack rather than a correct solution.

### Use EC2 instead.

---

I'm deploying a PHP application using following setup:

### Setup

1. Bitbucket pipeline builds the applucation using composer and creates a finished zip file.
2. Bitbucket AWS Elastic Beanstalk deploys the code to a AWS Elastic Beanstalk application.
3. The post install hook in **opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post** does run the PHP script after the deployment

## Problem

The PHP script which should be executed on the post deploy hook as a background task, never stops running. This effectively clogs the pipeline.

[Screenshot of Pipeline running forever (stopped on purpose)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EglEo.png)

[Bitbucket pipeline checking the **health status** of the AWS Elastic Beanstalk Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWseN.png)

Here is the code to the .ebextensions configuration file.

```
container_commands:
  01-create_post_hook:
    command: "mkdir -p /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post"
    ignoreErrors: true
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/start.sh":
    mode: "000770"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: | #!/bin/bash
      echo "--------Starting Runner------------"
      php /var/app/current/runner.php &
```

### Questions

- Is the bash script configured correctly **to run in the background**?
- Is there another (recommended) way to execute a script after the application has been updated?

### Notes

Since the script that is supposed to run in the background actually never finished, the health status of the application always remains at "info". This is a problem since it requires to be at "OK" for an application to be deployed successfully.

[Application Health Stuck at "Info" rather than "OK"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ts8j1.png)

Similar questions I've found throughout the internet:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=301439&tstart=0
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=425130&#425130

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, we use CI/CD (Continuous Integration/Continuous Delivery) tools, such as Jenkins, CircleCI or Bamboo to do these stuff. They can get a webhook from Bitbucket, which triggers any kind of task, like calling a PHP script, running a bash script, run a raketask, etc.